# Need to fix the following code

Tags: java, attributes

```
import java.util.*;


public class LifeSimulator{

    static String name= var;

    public static void Choice1(){

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

       LifeSimulator player= new LifeSimulator();

       System.out.println("Welcome to Life Simulator 2017! What is your name?");

       player.name= input.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Hello"+name);


}
```

Comment: - what is `var`, where is it declared?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LifeSimulator {

    static String name;

    public static void Choice1() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LifeSimulator player = new LifeSimulator();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Life Simulator 2017! What is your name?");
        player.name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: also try to give explanation to what changes have you made, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear code is as below.

import java.util.*;

public class LifeSimulator {
    static String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Life Simulator 2017! What is your name?");
        LifeSimulator.name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        input.close();
    }
}

Corrections
1. Class is not closed with }
2. Invalid variable assignment static String name= var;
3. Unused method Choice1()
4. static field name should be referred with class name LifeSimulator and not by it's object player.
```